# Microscope: relation between numearical aperture and working distance

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses, microscopy

I am looking for help in understanding the relation between the numercial aperture and the working distance of a microscope objective.

I've searched for many hours but couldn't find any paper / book or other literature that could tell me the relation between these two parameters.

Are there any formulas on how to calculate the working distance of an microscope objective?
I would also really appreciate literature recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

Working distance and numerical aperture are not directly related.  For a given numerical aperture, one can usually increase the working distance, but it requires making all the lens elements larger. (Yes, the prescription of the elements would also change when they get larger).  Hence for a given numerical aperture, there is a tradeoff between working distance and cost, because larger elements will cost more.

Because the weighting of cost is different for each application, you likely won't find this mentioned in books.  If lenses are specified with a back working distances of X mm, many designers will just make the back working distance be X + some small margin to accomodate tolerances.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Okay I get the Idea that you can make the elements larger in order to increase WD on a conceptual level.

But I'm still not sure how to even calculate the working distance of an objective with 2 lenses. I'm looking for some kind of equation that shows me the inverse nature between the working distance and let's say the magnification.

Assume I had two lenses with a given NA, focal length, and distance apart from each other. 
What would be the starting point in calculating the working distance of this objective?

Answer (score 0):

The working distance is a direct consequence of the actual optical design, and less so in regard to the numerical aperture (though one can indirectly affect the other).

Either way, as far as I know, there's no direct analytical relation between them in a real-world optical design (one may design different lenses with the same focal length and numerical aperture, but different working distances).